# How to parse an array of objects and save elements of specific attributes to a different array?

Tags: java, arrays, object

I have an array of call records and I want to store the ones that have a call disposition of "DNC" in a different array. The function opens a csv file and reads the entire file into an array of objects and sets the attributes. The original array contains 680 object records. I have an if statement after the my object setters that says if userArray[count].getDisposition == "DNC" then add this records to my new array DNC_List[dnc_count] and increment dnc_count++.

dnc_count is initialized to 0 and at the end of the process, it is still 0. There are 4 records in my original array that have "DNC" as an attribute. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code and why it is not recognizing when disposition is DNC?

```
public static void myCSVReader(String filename) {
    String path = "C:\\Users\\My_Username\\Downloads\\" + filename;
    file_path = path;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    String line = "";
    String csvSplitBy = ",";
    int count = 0;
    String fullName, U_ID;
    int dnc_count = 0;

    User userArray[] = new User[1000];
    User[] DNC_List = new User[1000];
    System.out.println("Starting csv reader");

    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] s = line.split(csvSplitBy);

            fullName = s[13] + " " + s[15];
            U_ID = s[44];
            userArray[count] = new User(s[1], s[2], s[0], fullName, U_ID);
            userArray[count].setDisposition(s[2]);
            userArray[count].setNumber(s[1]);
            userArray[count].setName(fullName);
            userArray[count].setID(U_ID);
            if(userArray[count].getDisposition() == "DNC" || userArray[count].getDisposition() == "CS"){
                DNC_List[dnc_count].setKey(String.valueOf(dnc_count));
                DNC_List[dnc_count].setDisposition("DNC");
                DNC_List[dnc_count].setName(userArray[dnc_count].getName());
                DNC_List[dnc_count].setID(userArray[dnc_count].getID());
                dnc_count++;
            }
            count++;
            User user = new User(s[1], s[2], s[0], fullName, U_ID);
            user.setDisposition(s[2]);
            user.setNumber(s[1]);
            user.setName(fullName);
            user.setID(U_ID);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Prints out the array index, name, disposition, and phone_number
    System.out.println("\n\nUser array: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < userArray.length; i++) {
        if (userArray[i] != null) {
            System.out.println(i + ": " + userArray[i].getName() + "\t | Dispo = " + userArray[i].getDisposition()
                    + "\t | Phone = " + userArray[i].getNumber());
        }
    }
    
    System.out.println("\nDNC_COUNT = " + dnc_count);
    for (int i = 0; i < dnc_count; i++) {
        System.out.println(DNC_List[i] + "\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `equals` to compare strings instead of `==`: `"DNC".equals( userArray[count].getDisposition())`

Answer (score 1):

The value of the string object can't be compared using '==' operator and should use the `equals()` method.

Change your comparison to use equals method of `String` class.

Use

```
userArray[count].getDisposition().equals("DNC") "CS"
```

instead of

```
userArray[count].getDisposition() == "DNC"
```

Comment: Awesome thank you so much. This solved my issue.

Comment: You are Welcome! and your upvote matters!

Comment: @Prabhu, such issue is a low-hanging fruit which is generally worth a comment.  And the question is very likely to be closed soon as a duplicate and then removed.

Comment: @AlexRudenko Does this effect my profile on stackoverflow if the question is closed for being a duplicate?

Comment: @AnthonyHorner, if the question is closed, it does not affect your reputation points, it just  won't allow new answers.  Only when a question is _removed_, all the related points (positive or negative) are discarded, however, the chances for "duplicate" questions to be removed are pretty high.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `equals()` method instead of `==`

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a = "DNC";
    String b = new String("DNC");
    System.out.println(a == b);
    System.out.println(a.equals(b));
  }
}
```

Output:

```
false
true
```

Comment: Thank you! This has resolved my problem

Comment: Great!! Please upvote and accept the answer by clicking the big green check box. :) enjoy!!

Comment: @Tushar, such issue is a low-hanging fruit which is generally worth a comment.  And the question is very likely to be closed soon as a duplicate and then removed.